# Break out of input.Scan()

Tags: go

I have this simple code to read all input from the console:

```
input := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin) //Creating a Scanner that will read the input from the console

for input.Scan() {
    if input.Text() == "end" { break } //Break out of input loop when the user types the word "end"
    fmt.Println(input.Text())
}
```

The code as it is works. What I want to do is get rid of the if-clause. In my understanding of the documentation if a line is empty `input.Scan()` should return false and therefore break out of the loop.

> Scan advances the Scanner to the next token, which will then be available through the Bytes or Text method. It returns false when the scan stops, either by reaching the end of the input or an error. After Scan returns false, the Err method will return any error that occurred during scanning, except that if it was `io.EOF`, Err will return nil. Scan panics if the split function returns 100 empty tokens without advancing the input. This is a common error mode for scanners.

Am I misinterpreting the documentation and it is actually necessary to have such a if-clause to break out? (I'm using Go 1.5.2 running the program using "go run".)

Comment: *What I want to do is get rid of the if-clause* Why is this an issue?

Comment: If I remove the if-clause, and just press Return, the program is not leaving the loop. On the console it just puts me on the next line. The code after the loop is not getting executed.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think you misread the documentation. The default scanner is ScanLines function.

Documentation says:

> ScanLines is a split function for a Scanner that returns each line of
>   text, stripped of any trailing end-of-line marker. The returned line
>   may be empty. The end-of-line marker is one optional carriage return
>   followed by one mandatory newline. In regular expression notation, it
>   is `\r?\n`. The last non-empty line of input will be returned even if
>   it has no newline.

Two important points here:

- *The return line may be empty*: It means it returns empty lines.
- *The last non-empty line of input will be returned even if it has no newline*: It means the last line of a file is always returned if it is non empty. It does not mean however an empty line end the stream.

The scanner will stop on EOF (End Of File). Typing Ctrl-D for example will send end of file and stop the scanner.

Comment: On windows use Ctrl-Z.

Answer (score 10):

Typing a blank new line will not automatically stop the scanner.

If it ain't broke, don't fix it--but you can make it behave as you require. This doesn't get rid of your `if` block but functions as you expected scanner to, i.e. hitting enter with no input will stop the scanner:

```
    input := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin) //Creating a Scanner that will read the input from the console

    for input.Scan() {
        if input.Text() == "" {
            break
        } 
        fmt.Println(input.Text())
    }
```

Comment: @Chris I saw Mickaël Rémond's technically accurate answer before posting mine, so I decided to focus on simply making the code perform as you seemed to want it to. Thanks for the up vote ;)

Answer (score 6):

`CTRL+D` to break,
if you want to input data easily, you can use `cat input.txt | go run script.go` or `go run script.go < input.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

You are not misinterpreting the documentation.

> It returns false when the scan stops, either **by reaching the end of the input** or an error.

What documentation states is correct. But you are missing that you need a way to provide end of the input i.e. EOF from the console.

In linux you can press "CTRL+D", which signals EOF from terminal.

Though there is a small catch here, that "CTRL+D" works only at the beginning of the line. Thus to terminate the input from terminal you need to go to a new line and press "CTRL+D" as first input on the line.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac systems, you can try `Ctrl + D` to break by default. If you are at the end of the line you will have to hit `Ctrl + D` **2 times**.

Answer (score 1):

For windows, the EOF for stdin is ctrl+Z, followed by enter.